# How to create an offline mirror of the npm registry

Tags: npm, offline, yarnpkg, offline-caching

Let's say we have someone traveling to an island with little to no internet connection. Instead of just lying at the beach and drinking Mojitos she wants to continue developing using the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/).

**Is there a way to create an full offline mirror of the npm registry including all attachments?**

There are many cache solutions out there but our island-traveler would actually need access to the whole registry without pre caching or online fallback.

How big is the whole npm registry including all attachments at the moment? Could the whole registry fit on a disk with a few Terabyte?